# How to fix error "Cannot load PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm trying to execute a Powershell script from an asp.net webpage and I keep getting this error when it tries to execute the script. I have tried 2 methods of executing the script and both give me the same error. The full error is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request
>   PSSnapInException: Cannot load PowerShell snap-in
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics because of the following error: Could
>   not load file or assembly
>   'C:\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands'. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Desktop\\test.ps1");
                powershell.AddScript(sr.ReadToEnd());
                var results = powershell.Invoke();
                if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    // error records were written to the error stream.
                    // do something with the items found.
                }
            }
```

```
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                {   
  PowerShellInstance.AddScript("C:\\Users\\RSpotton\\Desktop\\test.ps1");
                    PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
                }
```

Answer (score 61):

I had a similar issue and accompanying error message. Installing the *NuGet package* for `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` into my project did the trick.

Comment: It would be great if usage of powershell in C# was better documented. thanks BinaryBurnie. In case it helps anyone, found this documented in a github issue as well: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2108

Comment: Thank you! `dotnet add Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK`

Comment: In my case, I had to uninstall this package and install an older version (went from 7.1 to 6.2.7). The other related packages like System.Management.Autoamtion were 6.2.7 as well